# Compile error on only some devices

Tags: packages, compiling, compilation-error

This may be a basic question, but I don't have much knowledge about latex.
There is a .tex file I'm trying to compile.
However some of my colleagues are able to compile it without any error, I get this error on my laptop using this command in terminal: "pdflatex fileName.tex"

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: No counter 'theorem' defined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.20 \newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
> ```

These are the first lines of that file:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./}{Charts/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
```

I'm using a mac and this is my latex version:
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0

I'd appreciate if someone can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: you get that error in telive 2018 and 207 but not in 2016, one of the packages must have changed, I'll check....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simplify to

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous]{acmart}
\show\thetheorem
```

then in old releases you get

```
> \thetheorem=macro:
->\thesection .\arabic {theorem}.
```

showing the latex counter `theorem` is defined, but since 2017 you get

```
> \thetheorem=undefined.
l.2 \show\thetheorem
```

Looking at the code, `acmart` now  delays defining a `theorem` environment  so now you would need

```
\AtBeginDocument{\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}}
```

Comment: David I have already tried adding this line:
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
But somehow it messes up the format. The new pdf file looks different than what others get. It does not fit in the same number of pages as the other one. I need to get the exact same pdf file.

Comment: @Kat try sorry I was wrong to suggest that, see my edited answer. But there are 169 lines of acmart.cls that have changed between 2016 release and the current one. If the ACM choose to change their formatting it is hard for a user to insist they get identical formatting using the current version than they got with an old. You can of course get an old acmart.cls from the other machine and use it with texlive 2018, but if you are submitting to the ACM journal they will presumably be using the current one that you used, from 2018, so using an old release for your draft won't help.

Comment: I asked my colleague and they're using "Tex Live 2017" version and still don't get the error I'm getting.

Comment: @Kat it changed during 2018, so if you have an "original" texlive 2017 (as on the TUG CD) then you will have the old one, but I had a fully up to date tl2017 from just before it was frozen for texlive 2018, it is easy for you to check, the "new"  `acmart.cls`  file says `\ProvidesClass{acmart} [2018/02/07 v1.50 Typesetting articles for the Association for Computing Machinery]`  so it was updated in February of this year right at the end of the texlive 2017 cycle.

Comment: I've downloaded the same acmart.cls file (v1.39) that my colleagues use and put it in the same folder as the .tex files. I still don't get the same pdf. Mine has page numbers and theirs don't. Theirs have header on top of each page, and mine does not.

Comment: @Kat add `\listfiles` to your preamble then look at the file list at the end of the log and compare version numbers, some packages will have changed (the updated latex format in texlive 2018 would not change the layout so if you use all the same package files you will get the same output)